# Role based permission edit for plugins

Tags: plugins, users, editor, user-roles

I have TheThe Fly Image slider installed on my website which has multiple users. I wish to hide the settings from contributors and authors, but allow editors and admin roles to be able to amend the content within the slider.

I've installed a plugin to modify the capabilities of each role, but for some reason, options for TheThe Fly aren't available. I also have nextgen gallery installed and there are specific capabilities shown to edit for each role.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/thethe-image-slider/

Comment: not every plugin creates its own capabilities!

Answer (score 1):

I think the plugin include the possibility with one check for rights, for a capability. You see in the source of the plugin, that he include the menu items, if the user have the capability `edit_theme_options`. That makes not so easy for you to change this in different roles. You can create custom roles, like with the plugin "[Members](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/)" and change the capabilities on the role.

If you will only hide the areas, not check for the right on the different roles, then use the plugin "[Adminimize](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/adminimize/)".

Also it is possible to hide via custom source and also it is possible to change capabilities via custom source, but not so easy as add the plugins and use it.